# making low poly furry cloth

Tags: modeling

This is an illustration of a furry skirt for a game for a character.
[image]

What are the possible approaches to convey this sort of furry cloth for a low poly cloth for game? I tried to pole the cloth(hotkey P) and use spikes, which was frowned upon, what are other approaches? (This has to be done in model and not with texture or particle systems)